# Report - Show Group if One Value Equals

Tags: reporting, filters

I have a report where groups are listed with their various products:

| Group Number | Product |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | One |
| 1 | Two |
| 1 | Four |
| 2 | One |
| 2 | Two |
| 2 | Three |
| 3 | Two |
| 3 | Four |

How do I filter this report to show only groups that contain a specific product, but show all products? For instance, if I only wanted to see groups that have product Four, the report should look like this:

| Group Number | Product |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | One |
| 1 | Two |
| 1 | Four |
| 3 | Two |
| 3 | Four |

Is there a way to do this? How do I filter this way?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a cross filter like this: With Products Where Product Name equals Four.

So, first, you add a cross filter for "with Products". Then, underneath the cross filter, you can specify a sub-filter. In this case, I added Product Name and "equals Four".